# Trying to get soapclient add xsi:type to request

Tags: php, arrays, soap

So Im passing a field of array items to a web service call and the request and response looks ok, but Im trying to get the Value attribute to tell the type, so this is my fields:

```
$fields = array(
           "Password"=>'password',
           "entity"=>array(
                      "Name" =>"namehere",
                      "Id"=>'1234',
                      "Attributes"=>
                        array(
                            array(
                                "AttributeType"=>'SingleLineOfText',
                                "Key"=>'Key1',
                                "Value"=>'1',
                            ),
                            array(
                                "AttributeType"=>'SingleLineOfText',
                                "Key"=>'Key2',
                                "Value"=>'2',
                            ),
                            array(
                                "AttributeType"=>'DateAndTime',
                                "Key"=>'Key3',
                                "Value"=>'2016-09-16T00:00:00'
                            )

                        )
                    )
                );
```

So my REQUEST is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP- 
 ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
 xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:Create> 
 <ns1:Password>password</ns1:Password><ns1:entity> 
 <ns1:Name>namehere</ns1:Name><ns1:Id>1234</ns1:Id><ns1:Attributes><ns1:Attribute> 
 <ns1:AttributeType>SingleLineOfText</ns1:AttributeType> 
 <ns1:Key>Key1</ns1:Key><ns1:Value>1</ns1:Value> 
 </ns1:Attribute><ns1:Attribute> 
 <ns1:AttributeType>SingleLineOfText</ns1:AttributeType> 
 <ns1:Key>Key2</ns1:Key><ns1:Value>2</ns1:Value> 
 </ns1:Attribute><ns1:Attribute> 
 <ns1:AttributeType>DateAndTime</ns1:AttributeType> 
 <ns1:Key>Key3</ns1:Key><ns1:Value>2016-09-16T00:00:00</ns1:Value></ns1:Attribute></ns1:Attributes></ns1:entity> 
 </ns1:Create></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

So you can see < ns1:Value >1< /ns1:Value > but I need it to be like able to determine what the type is so like < Value xsi:type="xsd:string" >1< /Value> or  < Value xsi:type="xsd:dateTime" >2016-09-16T00:00:00< /Value> if its a date field, I have tried to do loop through and assign it but it does not seem to work, here is the loop I have tried

```
foreach($fields['entity']['Attributes'] as $attribute){
                echo $attribute['Value'] = new SoapVar($attribute, XSD_STRING, "string", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
            }
```